# Populate LDAP with credentional for CAS

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, cas

I run an instance of CAS project and also run an OpenLdap server.
I want to signUp some user in cas(or ldap).
Where can I add users? in ldap or in CAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS does not maintain user accounts. You must store them in a store. This could be LDAP, flat file, RDBMS, RADIUS, etc... In your case you'll want to store them in LDAP. How you get them into LDAP (sign up) will be left an en exercise for you.